# error C2065: undeclared identifier in template function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

I'm a newbie in C++ and i'm trying to put a little project on wheels, but i'm having a hard time with those errors and i don't know what i'm doing wrong. I think, i've included all neccesary header files.
What i'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

`d:\files\visual studio 2010\projects\calculator\aplicatie.cpp(31): error C2065: 'CmdAritmetice' : undeclared identifier`

`d:\files\visual studio 2010\projects\calculator\aplicatie.cpp(31): error C2062: type 'int' unexpected`

`d:\files\visual studio 2010\projects\calculator\aplicatie.cpp(37): error C2065: 'cmd1' : undeclared identifier`

`d:\files\visual studio 2010\projects\calculator\aplicatie.cpp(37): error C2228: left of '.Execute' must have class/struct/union`

`type is ''unknown-type''`

**Edit**

If i modify `CmdAritmetice <int, Suma> cmd1("+");` with `UI::CmdAritmetice<Calcule::Suma<int>> cmd1("+");` the following errors appear when try to compile:

```
1>d:\files\visual studio 2010\projects\calculator\aplicatie.cpp(32): error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'T (__cdecl *)(T,T)' to 'int (__cdecl *)(int,int)'
1>          None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
1>d:\files\visual studio 2010\projects\calculator\aplicatie.cpp(39): error C2660: 'Calculator::UI::CmdAritmetice<Operatie>::Execute' : function does not take 1 arguments
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Operatie=0x0
1>          ]
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "aplicatie.h"
using namespace Calculator;

int main()

{
    Aplicatie app;
    app.Run();
    return 0;
}
```

**aplicatie.cpp** edited

```
#include <iostream>
#include "aplicatie.h"
#include "Calcule\operatii.h"
#include "UI\cmdaritmetice.h"

using namespace std;

namespace Calculator{

(...)

    void Aplicatie::Run()
    {
        TestSuma();
        CmdAritmetice <int, Suma> cmd1("+");     //here i have errors
        cmd1.Execute("Introduceti doua numere intregi (x, y)");
    }

    void Aplicatie::TestSuma()
    {
        int x = 10, y = 20;
        int r = Calcule::Suma(x,y);
    }    
}
```

**cmdaritmetice.h**

```
#ifndef ARITMETICE_H
#define ARITMETICE_H
#include "UI\comanda.h"

namespace Calculator{
    namespace UI{

        template<int Operatie(int, int)>
        class CmdAritmetice : public ComandaCalcule
        {

        public:
            CmdAritmetice(const string &nume) : ComandaCalcule(nume)
            {
            }
            void Execute()
            {
            cout << Nume() << endl;
            cout << "Introduceti doua numere intregi (x, y)\n";
            int x, y;
            cin >> x >> endl;
            cin >> y >> endl;
            cout << x << " " << Nume() << " " << y << " = " << Operatie (x,y) <<endl;
            }
        };
    }
}
#endif
```

**LE**

```
**operatii.h**

#ifndef OPERATII_H
#define OPERATII_H

namespace Calculator{
    namespace Calcule{

    template<typename T>
    T Suma(T x, T y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CmdAritmetice` is defined in namespace `Calculator::UI` while `Aplicatie` is defined in namespace `Calculator`. So, you must refer to `CmdAritmetice` as `UI::CmdAritmetice` within the `Calculator` namespace.

As for error saying `Suma` cannot be found, you haven't posted the definition of `Suma`, so it's hard to say what's going on there, but check to make sure that that too isn't defined within some nested namespace.

EDIT:
The definition for `CmdAritmetice` is

```
template<int Operatie(int, int)>
class CmdAritmetice : public ComandaCalcule
{
    // ...
};
```

So it takes a template argument that is function with the signature `int(int, int)`, i.e. a function that accepts 2 `int`s and returns an `int`. Within `Aplicatie::Run()` you try to instantiate the class as

```
CmdAritmetice <int, Suma>
```

Obviously this will not work, the template argument needs to be a function matching the signature you've specified in the definition. Also, references to `Suma` need to be qualified as `Calcule::Suma`.

I think what you intend to do is

```
UI::CmdAritmetice<Calcule::Suma<int>> cmd1("+");
```

Comment: If i modify the line like this `UI::CmdAritmetice <int, Suma> cmd1("+");` i get error C2514: 'Calculator::UI::CmdAritmetice' : class has no constructors. But it has in cmdaritmetice.h `public:
CmdAritmetice(const string &nume) : ComandaCalcule(nume)  {}`

Comment: @Zodrak You don't show that you include any standard library headers other than `<iostream>`, and that one doesn't contain the definition of `string`. Without the definition of `string`, the compiler cannot know that `"+"` can be converted to `string`.

Comment: @hvd i've included `string`, but nothing changes. it says: "identifier cmdAritmetice is undefined"

Comment: @Zodrak If you now get a different error message, something did change... C++ is case sensitive, you defined the class `CmdAritmetice`, not `cmdAritmetice`.

Comment: @hvd in fact it didn't. this message appears when i hover the mouse on CmdAritmetice.i'm getting the errors posted above when i try to compile. someone told me that C++ needs patience, now i understand

Comment: @Zodrak I've added to my answer. If you're getting more errors please apply the fixes mentioned so far, and update the question.

Comment: @Zodrak You're calling `CmdAritmetice::Execute()` with a string literal argument (`cmd1.Execute("...");`) but the function takes 0 arguments. And the second error message states that very clearly! Not sure what's causing the first error message, but here's [a similar example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebd6098d3dc5a3f1) that compiles successfully. Maybe you could try to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and post that. And this might be a copy-paste error but the closing brace for `namespace Calcule` is missing in *operatii.h*